# Ruby—nested gsubs?

Tags: ruby, gsub

I'm parsing a txt file (an old hymns book). I want to do the following:

- Get the chorus
- Parse/santize each line of that chorus

I've tried this code:

```
chorus_regex = /([^0-9]+\n)+/
puts hymn.gsub(chorus_regex) {|match| match.gsub(/^([^0-9]+\n)/, "  \1")}
```

But the second `gsub` is only affecting the first line? I think it's because the `\1` might be applied to the first regex, not the second

#### TL;DR

How do you write nested gsubs, so that you can grab blocks of txt, do a gsub on those blocks, and replace the old blocks with the results?

---

**Edit**

I simplified the regexes, so the question is focused on how to nest regex gsubs, and not distracted by complicated regex or badly encoded chars.

Comment: An example would be helpful.

Comment: Why does your text file contain "�"? That looks like a broken encoding.

Comment: @Stefan yep, I'm sanitizing a fairly broken document

Answer (score 0):

To nest gsubs, make sure you use blocks for the gsubs, and you can use the perlisms ($1 for first group, etc).

```
chorus_regex = /([^0-9]+\n)+/
puts hymn.gsub(chorus_regex) {|match| 
  match.gsub(/^([^0-9]+\n)/) { |line| 
    "  #{$1}"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you wanted to share a knowledge, it would make sense to come up with a less contrived more explicit example instead of these weird “�”s.

Comment: @mudasobwa that was a specific problem I had—then I found the solution, so I put it here because I couldn't find it elsewhere on stack overflow

Comment: Nested `gsub`s act exactly the same as nested `map`s, nested `reduce`s and basically any nested function that accepts a block.